# Xamarin Android: Recent Apps and Activities

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I've been developing my first Xamarin Android App in C# for a few weeks. My approach at separating different aspects of the app from each other was to have multiple activities:
One for the Login
One for the main menu
One for the Settings
...

While navigating through my app I noticed that each Activity I opened is shown under recent apps. To counter this I started finishing the current activity before launching the new one using an intent aswell overwriting the OnBackPressed in each Activity to control which Activity will be loaded next.

Is this bad design? How do the usual apps one know behave? I never noticed that an app is listed multiple times under recent apps so I feel like I do something wrong.
Is the state of art to have one activity and handle everything with fragments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question which is difficult to answer, as there are advantages and drawbacks of both strategies.

In essence, most people prefer to use fragments nowadays for multiple reasons:

- Activities are more memory intensive,
- It is easier to handle your navigation stack by using the `FragmentManager`
- Fragments are adaptable for both phone and tables
- Compared to activities, fragments are easier to re-use
- A fragment cannot exist on its own, as it must be a part of an activity
- Fragments are although more complex to implement compared to activities

In the end, it is really up to you which strategy you decide to use. But as you pointed out yourself, your activities will show up in the list of most recent applications. That won't be the case when using Fragments.

Comment: Perfect answer. I will try to build my next app around fragments. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You are welcome, @Zz993. Please don't forget to accept the answer if you found what you needed, so that others don't respond thinking that your question has not been answered. It would also help me in the same time :)